# IPhone App Crashes on Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a simple app (this is my first one) which loads an image from my resources folder, I change my image like this (with the image name changing):

```
myUIImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nextImage.jpg"];
```

It runs really well on the app I can change the image an infinite number of times. But when I run it on my Ipod Touch, it crashes after the image changes about 4 times. Do I need to release the image when I change it? It certainly seems to be a memory issue,

I should mention each image is like 200kb.

The console reads this when it crashes:

```
Program received signal:  “0”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")
```

Any advice would help,
Thanks!

Comment: That line shouldn't crash, nor do you need to release it, as imageNamed: gives an autoreleased object. Please provide more code, or the crash error message and stacktrace.

Comment: This line might not be the culprit because it's perfectly fine.  [UIImage imageNamed] is autorelease, and myUIImageView.image is retained.  The problem might be elsewhere, are you releasing your myUIImageView ?

Comment: I am not releasing it, sorry I'm a bit a of newbie in this area, I've ran it on my device with the Activity Monitor and the VM Size seems to be really high, how do I release myUIIMageView?

Comment: call [myUIImageView release] will release the UIImageView

Comment: does this need to happen only in - (void)dealloc ? I've edited my question with what the console reads at crash

Comment: The console log is not helpful. I hate seeing that message too. Can you check if the stacktrace is logged in the debugger? Or provide more code that we can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that it runs really well, do you mean it runs really well on the simulator?

I've found that its not good to check for memory problems on the simulator: it tends to be way too powerful compared to an actual device. The crash may not be on your image swapping code at all.

I recommend you go over your code and check for leaks. Also monitor it using Instruments->Leaks while running on the device, not on simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you release object somewhere. It really looks like wrong use of release method.